# BFS and finding the shortest path through an adjacency matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, graph, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to implement BFS and finding the shortest path through an adjacency matrix. But BFS almost always returns the result of false. What am I doing wrong?

```
private static bool BFS(int[,] adj, int src, int dest, int v, int[] pred, int[] dist)
        {
            Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();
            bool[] visited = new bool[v];
            for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
            {
                visited[i] = false;
                dist[i] = int.MaxValue;
                pred[i] = -1;
            }
            visited[src] = true;
            dist[src] = 0;
            queue.Enqueue(src);

            while (queue.Count != 0)
            {
             
               int u= queue.Dequeue();

                for (int i = 0; i < adj.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    if (visited[i] == false && adj[u,i]!=0)
                    {
                        visited[i] = true;
                        dist[i] = dist[u] + 1;
                        pred[i] = u;
                        queue.Enqueue(i);

                        // stopping condition (when we
                        // find our destination)
                        if (i == dest)
                            return true;
                    }
                    visited[u] = true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The queue doesn't look correct.  It looks like you only have one node in the queue.

Comment: @jdweng I edited the code in the post, but now it always outputs a path of length 1 and shows the path directly from the source to the destination, although they are not directly connected

Comment: The best way of debugging is to create an output file and add debug message to the file.  Then look at file to understand what is happening.  Recursive algorithms are always difficult to debug.  Looking at the file always makes it easier for me to get code working.

Comment: @jdweng: There is no recursion in the given algorithm.

Comment: @Xaver : I know.  OP is using push/pop instead of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < adj.GetLength(0); i++)
```

This looks wierd to me.  Should it not be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < adj.GetLength( u ); i++)
```